# How to speed up GeoWithinQ?

Tags: regions, geography, geographics, expression-test

`GeoWithinQ` is a very useful function - is this point within this area? However, it is quite slow. It's not unheard of to have large numbers of points - for instance, global satellite measurements at a high resolution. I have used satellite data with millions of pixels - ie, data points.

Let's say I have 100,000 points and I would like to check whether they are within the polygon of France. However, doing

```
points = RandomGeoPosition[100000]
Select[points, GeoWithinQ[Entity["Country","France"]]]
```

times out. The documentation has another example that uses `Pick` instead of `Select`.

```
Pick[points, GeoWithinQ[Entity["Country","France"], points]
```

This too times out, but it is significantly faster for a smaller number of points (I've managed about 1,000 before hitting major performance issues).

My question is, how do I use `GeoWithinQ` for 100,000 points and more?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `RegionMember` and the region functionality to make this a *lot* faster, at the expense of a smaller functionality, and potentially missing out some details about geodesy, as well as losing out on `GeoModel` and the like. This approach also doesn't use the network (other than getting the entity's polygon), so it is better suited for network-constrained development. (`GeoWithinQ` actually uses the network!)

We generate our points:

```
points = Thread @ RandomGeoPosition[100000]
```

(we `Thread` here so we have 100,000 `GeoPosition` objects rather than one `GeoPosition` object with 100,000 sub-points)

Then, we set up a `RegionMemberFunction` using the polygon for `France`. We strip the `GeoPosition` heads out of the Polygon, because `RegionMember` can't work with them*:

```
rm = RegionMember[
  Entity["Country", "France"]["Polygon"] /. GeoPosition[x_] -> x]
```

and then we `Select` based on this `RegionMemberFunction`, again stripping the `GeoPosition` head out.

```
Select[points, rm[# /. GeoPosition[x_] -> x] &]
```

This takes about 5 seconds on my machine.

`Pick` in this case is even faster:

```
Pick[points, rm[points /. GeoPosition[x_] -> x]]
```

which takes just over a second on my machine.

It's a pity that `GeoWithinQ` doesn't have `PerformanceGoal` or similar so that we can ask it to be less exact, but faster.

*in version 12.2, `RegionMember` can work with them, but typically creates a 3-dimensional region, which takes much longer to check against

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you for literally saving me hours of time!