# GeoGraphics issues URLFetch Error

Tags: geographics

With Mathematica 12.31 and 13 on Windows 10 when executing any command with GeoGraphics
gives the error:
URLFetch::invhttp: A library error occurred. The raw details are: "libcurl error (28): Operation timed out after 10001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received"

Is this only on my system?

```
GeoGraphics[]
```

Comment: This also works fine for me. Have you tried using a different `GeoServer`? Try something like `GeoGraphics[GeoServer -> "http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/\`1\`/\`2\`/\`3\`.png"]`. It's possible that the Wolfram tileserver is on the blink or that something is blocking the requests.

Comment: @CarlLange hmm.. that seems to work.

Comment: In that case it seems likely that something is causing your requests to the Wolfram tileserver to stop working. See if http://geo.wolfram.com might be blocked on your network (it will give `Forbidden` if you go to it in a browser).

Comment: @CarlLange, I'm seeing Forbidden on my home network. Do you know the cause and a fix (other than using a different GeoServer)?

Comment: Well, `Forbidden` is expected (and likely a good sign), since the request isn't coming from Mathematica. Unfortunately I have no idea what the cause is, and I can't reproduce it locally. You may need to contact Wolfram's support about this.

Comment: @david Sorry, I didn't realise you weren't the original asker. Either way, Forbidden is expected when accessing from the browser. You would probably need to add a MITM proxy to trace the requests to the tileserver in order to know what headers to send to fool the server into thinking you are Mathematica (in case that's what you're asking)

Comment: @CarlLange, the reason I asked is that I've been getting a Network timeout message when trying to use GeoIdentify on WeatherStation Entities. Whenever I pass a "large" number (>1459), I get the timeout. Less than that, it works. I saw this question and thought there might be some overlap with my issue. Thanks for the info. I'll continue my troubleshooting. BTW, GeoGraphics[] works without modification for me.

Comment: @david I believe `GeoIdentify` uses an implementation of OpenStreetMaps' [Nominatim](https://nominatim.org/) service that runs on Wolfram's infrastructure. Depending on what you need, you may be able to query a different instance of that service. This Q&A of mine may also be of interest: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/195482/how-to-speed-up-geowithinq/195483#195483 You could also stand up an instance of Nominatim yourself, or an instance of PostGIS, which also has some geocoding built-in (iirc).

Comment: @CarlLange, that looks promising. I see that your Q&A discusses performance. I had also noted that the performance of some these Geo functions get quite slow with many points. Your post will come in handy. Thx.

Comment: I'll contact Wolfram services but I'm afraid it's a corporate firewall or zscaler or anything else to prevent people from doing usefull stuf :)

Comment: @CarlLange And 10 minutes later it suddenly worked. Perhaps threatening with logging a case made the difference?